# Blazegraph INSERT DATA crashes with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

In Blazegraph I attempted the following query:

```
INSERT DATA {
    <http://my.site/User/instances/1>
    :comment
    <http://my.site/Comment/instances/16>.
}
```

and it crashes with the following exception trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.SPARQLStarUpdateDataBlockParser.read()I
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.SPARQLStarUpdateDataBlockParser.checkSparqlStarSyntax(SPARQLStarUpdateDataBlockParser.java:107)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.SPARQLStarUpdateDataBlockParser.parseValue(SPARQLStarUpdateDataBlockParser.java:100)
    at org.openrdf.rio.trig.TriGParser.parseGraph(TriGParser.java:158)
    at org.openrdf.repository.sail.helpers.SPARQLUpdateDataBlockParser.parseGraph(SPARQLUpdateDataBlockParser.java:87)
    at org.openrdf.rio.trig.TriGParser.parseStatement(TriGParser.java:128)
    at org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser.parse(TurtleParser.java:214)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.UpdateExprBuilder.doUnparsedQuadsDataBlock(UpdateExprBuilder.java:746)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.UpdateExprBuilder.visit(UpdateExprBuilder.java:161)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.UpdateExprBuilder.visit(UpdateExprBuilder.java:119)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.ast.ASTInsertData.jjtAccept(ASTInsertData.java:23)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.sparql.Bigdata2ASTSPARQLParser.parseUpdate2(Bigdata2ASTSPARQLParser.java:289)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.BigdataSailRepositoryConnection.prepareNativeSPARQLUpdate(BigdataSailRepositoryConnection.java:278)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.BigdataSailRepositoryConnection.prepareUpdate(BigdataSailRepositoryConnection.java:182)
    at org.openrdf.repository.base.RepositoryConnectionBase.prepareUpdate(RepositoryConnectionBase.java:180)
```

However normal `DELETE INSERT WHERE` queries work fine.

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates that you have multiple version of the same library in your project. Please check the `*.jar` files in the classpath.

Comment: No I have definitely checked there are no multiples: I have only 1 entry in relation to the only relevant dependency library in my build.gradle: `compile group: 'com.blazegraph', name: 'bigdata-core', version: '2.1.4'` and that's it. There is NOTHING else relevant to bigdata or blazegraph in any of my dependencies. Therefore, it should just work.

Comment: Well, and I'm sure that there is a conflict. For instance, you're using OpenRDF Sesame, right? And I guess there is a conflict between the Blazegraph supported version and the one that you're using. Blazegraph 2.1.4 uses Sesame 2.7.12 (see http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/blazegraph/blazegraph-parent/2.1.4/blazegraph-parent-2.1.4.pom) - and you're probably using some different version

Comment: Ok thanks, I will change my Sesame version to match 2.7.12 and see if it works. Is that what you mean? I'll let you know as soon as I've tried it.

Comment: It works! You're a star. If you can put an answer I'll upvote and mark it as answered. I was using Sesame 2.8.6. Although there were not multiple sesame jars as such in the classpath (just 2.8.6), changing 2.8.6 to 2.7.12 fixed the issue. Removing the gradle entry for sesame-runtime altogether also fixed the issue because bigdata-core includes sesame-runtime, so I have done that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can also provide the answer if you want. I think you can describe problem and solution better then me. This might help other people. Don't forget to accept your own answer then! Glad to hear that it works now. Good luck with the further project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removed the following line in my build.gradle:

```
compile('org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-runtime:2.8.6')
```

and refreshed dependencies. You simply don't need to declare a Sesame dependency if you're using bigdata-core, since Sesame is already a sub-dependency of that.

The reason for the crash was that bigdata-core relies on Sesame version 2.7.12 which was being superseded by my 2.8.6 declaration, which doesn't have an implementation of the method called, and hence the crash.

Thanks to @AKSW for the guidance behind this solution.